# how to access the button in custom dialog?

Tags: android, dialog

private void opendialog1() {

```
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom);
    dialog.show();
    btn = findViewById(R.id.cab);

    fusedLocationProviderClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if(ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity4.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){

                getlocation();
            }else{

                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity4.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 44);
            }
        }
```

}

Null pointer exception is occuring on OnclickListenser set on btn

Comment: try `btn = dialog.findViewById(R.id.cab);`

Comment: thankyou! its working now.